# How can I move a 500 lb wooden table top into my basement down a flight of stairs?

Tags: table, workshop

I am planning to install a large wooden work table in my basement. The top is 10 x 4 x 3" which means it will weigh about 500 pounds.

The problem is: how do I get it into the basement? The only access to the basement is down a flight of stairs. It is a straight shot, no turns, but I still need to get it down the stairs without damaging anything, so sliding is not a good idea.

Even with 4 men, each can only lift about 100 pounds, so that is not enough strength, and I don't see how I could get more than 4 men lifting the table. In fact, going down the stairs, it would be difficult to fit more than 2 men, one at either end.

Comment: why is sliding not a good idea? can the table legs come apart?

Comment: @depperm I only need to move the top, the legs are separate. The top weighs 500 lbs.

Comment: Wait, 4 men can't carry 500 pounds together? Oh, you mean 4 boys can't carry 500 pounds.

Comment: @Gunner - I think the problem is fitting 4 men carrying the top in the stairwell at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

That is a *big* piece of wood.  There are three obvious approaches:

1. Get some professionals to do it.  A grand piano weighs more than that (and is more awkwardly shaped).  Professionals will have the experience and equipment to do it safely, and the indemnity insurance to pay if anything gets damaged.
2. Slide it *gently* down the stairs (possibly manufacturing a slideway out of a plank or two, or just cover the steps with blankets).  Use ropes looped around the table to restrain it, and possibly a block and tackle to reduce the load until it is manageable.  (With the block and tackle, you can probably arrange not to have anyone standing below the table as it goes down - which strikes me as desirable).
3. Don't try and move the top as a single element.  There is no way it can be made of a single lump of solid wood, so buy the elements separately, and assemble them at the bottom of the stairs.

Comment: Its a butcher block table

Comment: Humans have been sliding heavier things for years, so good answer. Option 2 is well written and what I have done for similar situations.

Comment: @SolarMike s/years/millennia/

Comment: Like option #2, have done it like that before but it was too hard to type all of it out before coffee.

Comment: The local rigging company is handy to have in your phone book. Well worth the price for their experience and tools.  I can buy the tools, but have limited need for them, and far less experience in how things go wrong and how not to have them go wrong. They move my big hunks of cast iron from awkward places to other awkward places and make it look easy, for a fee that is very reasonable.

Comment: @Ecnerwal It looks easy because it *is* easy ... for them.

Comment: @MartinBonner I know that quite well, which is why I CALL them rather than trying to BE them.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Better their back than yours.

Comment: Don't consider cutting a butcher block into pieces without first checking for metal rods inside. Some are held together with internal threaded metal rods.

Comment: I did something similar when I got my new lathe. I put down a ramp of plywood and planks, then secured a come-along to the lathe and secured the other end to a 4x4 post on the other side of another doorway. I left enough slack in the cable so that I was able to push the lathe onto the ramp with a slight downward tilt, then I slowly slackened the come-along to move it down the ramp to the bottom.

Comment: Piano movers attach a "sled" to the piano and slide it around. Up and down stairs, etc. It's easier to make a sled than it is to make a stair-length ramp, IMO. Controlling the mass is the tricky part....

Answer (score 0):

### This is a job for a rigger

Same thing the Egyptians did with pyramid blocks.  Block and tackle, winches, slides, leverage, etc.  except with safety.

For something 500lb, your back is at no risk because handling it with muscle is *simply out of the question*.  The only body part capable of moving that your brain.

You might build a cradle for it, to assure it always stays vertical and you aren't tempted to keep it vertical using muscle power, which would go right until everything goes wrong very very quickly.

Comment: *"The only body part capable of moving that your brain."* Nice!